# JQuery button each click, show/hide forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hide, show

Guess I'm just starting out here, so might as well look for any kind of help since I'm quite frustrated with this novice question...

I have a button that shows a form I created, with 1 click, but the problem comes when I want to show another form that comes with another button.

What I want, basically is that `buttonA` shows `formA`, but when I click `buttonB`, I want to hide `formA` and show `formB`. Now what's happening is that it's overlaying `formA` and `formB`.

Here's my current code..

```
function runEffect() {
  $( "#effect" ).show( "drop");
};

function runEffect2() {
  $( "#effect2" ).show( "drop");
};


//callback function to bring a hidden box back
function hideEffect() {
    $( "#effect:visible" ).hide( "drop");

};

// set effect from select menu value

$( "#button" ).each(function(index) {
  $(this).click(function(){
  runEffect();
    });
});

$( "#button2" ).each(function(index) {
  $(this).click(function(){
  runEffect2();
    });
});

$( "#effect" ).hide();
$( "#effect2" ).hide();
```

I know this is easy, but I can't seem to find the answer to it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function runEffect() {
  $( "#effect" ).show( "drop");
  $( "#effect2" ).hide( "drop");
};

function runEffect2() {
 $( "#effect2" ).show( "drop");
 $( "#effect" ).hide( "drop");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#buttonB').click(funciton()(
$('#formA').hide();
$('#formB').show();
});
```

something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but maybe you want to a more dynamic function.
Button class must be something like "formButton" and the id like "form1Button", the form id then should be "form1" and so on..

(Form 2 would have a button with class "formButton", id like "form2Button" and form 2 needs id "form2"

```
$(".formButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var formId = id.replace('Button', '');

    $('#' + formId).show(); 
    $('form').not(document.getElementById(formId)).hide();

});
```

When a formButton is clicked, the form will be shown. All other forms, wich do not have the requested ID, will be hidden.